# Simple HTML to PDF python library error

Tags: python, pdf

I'm using this [pydf](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/pydf) to convert HTML to a PDF on our server. This is an example that comes right from their docs that illustrates the problem:

```
import pydf

pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>this is html</h1>')
with open('test_doc.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

---

When I go to run this file, I get the same error everytime:

```
(pdf) <computer>:<folder> <user>$ python pdf.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf.py", line 3, in <module>
    pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>this is html</h1>')
  File "/Users/nilesbrandon/Projects/pdf/pdf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 121, in generate_pdf
    return gen_pdf(html_file.name, cmd_args)
  File "/Users/nilesbrandon/Projects/pdf/pdf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 105, in gen_pdf
    _, stderr, returncode = execute_wk(*cmd_args)
  File "/Users/nilesbrandon/Projects/pdf/pdf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 22, in execute_wk
    p = subprocess.Popen(wk_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

I'm running this in a `virtualenv` and my `pip freeze` is only the following:

```
python-pdf==0.30
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using macOS, you need to download a wkhtmltopdf binary by your own:

> pydf comes bundled with a wkhtmltopdf binary which will only work on Linux amd64 architectures. If you're on another OS or architecture your milage may vary, it is likely that you'll need to supply your own wkhtmltopdf binary and point pydf towards it by setting the WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH variable.

Comment: Could you explain some steps I need to take to download a wkhtmltopdf binary on my own? Not sure where to start with that.

Comment: first download wkhtmltopdf from [its website](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) or with homebrew-cask, then set a env variable `WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: still having the issue actually.

Comment: @qarthandso what is your new issue?